# How to load .fas file and run command on every drawing load in autocad2012?

Tags: autocad, liskov-substitution-principle

Hello I am using Autocad2012 and I am trying to load a simple "XYZ.fas" file in autocad and want to run the command "XYZ" on every drawing load. I have tried adding the XYZ.fas in the Startup Suite and in acaddoc.lsp I wrote the following code:

```
(defun S::STARTUP()
(command "XYZ")
)
```

and by doing this only half of the job is done only the .fas file is loaded but it is not accepting the command. 
but if I write the command manually its running smoothly. Really hard for me to understand where I am wrong any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ACDOC.LSP file.

```
(setq dir "C:/LISP")
(load (strcat dir "/XYZ.fas")
(c:XYZ)
```